# Removing RAID device from RAID5 (shrinking RAID) without unmounting

Tags: raid, raid5

New to RAID and Linux. I grew my RAID5 array from 3 to 4 devices. For other reasons, I had to fail and remove one of the 4 drives - `sda1`. I'd like to shrink it now back to 3 devices, but when trying to do so, I'm getting a `new_offset` error:

```
# mdadm --grow --raid-devices=3  /dev/md127
mdadm: Cannot set new_offset for /dev/sdb1
```

Some notes:

- The array is mounted at `/`, so I'd like to avoid having to unmount it.
- There is data on the array, so I'd like to preserve it.

RAID details:

```
/dev/md127:
        Version : 1.1
  Creation Time : Mon Oct 22 16:20:37 2012
     Raid Level : raid5
     Array Size : 1953518592 (1863.02 GiB 2000.40 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 976759296 (931.51 GiB 1000.20 GB)
   Raid Devices : 4
  Total Devices : 3
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

  Intent Bitmap : Internal

    Update Time : Tue Nov  8 17:09:28 2016
          State : active, degraded
 Active Devices : 3
Working Devices : 3
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

  Delta Devices : 1, (3->4)

           Name : xxx
           UUID : xxx
         Events : 275192

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       3       8       49        0      active sync   /dev/sdd1
       2       0        0        2      removed
       4       8       33        2      active sync   /dev/sdc1
       6       8       17        3      active sync   /dev/sdb1
```

Can I fail and remove `/dev/sdb1` from the array? I imagine that would solve the error message, but I worry that in growing the array to 4 devices, failing 2 of them will render it irreparable. If that can't be done, what can be?

**Update**

Worked around the headache. `rsync`ed the contents of the degraded array to a backup drive, replaced the RAID with fresh-baked drives, then `rsync`ed back.

Comment: hmm... I never knew that you can shrink the number of disks in a RAID with a command line in Linux. In a Windows world, taking an image of the data to an external location, rearranging the RAID and then copy back the image would do it.

Comment: @NoorKhaldi: You're right. There is no way in Linux.

Comment: @NoorKhaldi I'm growing more convinced that that's the way to do it. But it'd be nice if there was a way that didn't involve shutting things off while the array was being set up

Comment: It seems you forgot to use resize2fs first

Answer (score 2):

You can do it but you need to specify a backup file in the command line. In your case something like

```
mdadm --grow --raid-devices=3  /dev/md127 --backup-file /root/md127.backup
```

should work.

If you have a usb stick or some other storage that isn't in the array, use it for backup file.